# Getting Inconsistent Accessibility error on public interface

Tags: c#

Ok, so I know this is a bit of a common question, but the answer has always seemed to be to set the interface to public. Well my interface is public, and I'm getting this error

*Error  CS0050  Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'IEnumerable<LoadData> is less accessible than method 'ILoanSelector.SelectSerials()'*

Here is my code.

```
namespace EscrowAnalysis
{
    public interface ILoanSelector
    {
        IEnumerable<LoanData> SelectSerials();
    }

    class LoanSelector : ILoanSelector
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; }
        public string LinkedServer { get; private set; }

        public LoanSelector(string connectionString, string linkedServer)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linkedServer)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(linkedServer));

            ConnectionString = connectionString;
            LinkedServer = linkedServer;
        }

        public IEnumerable<LoanData> SelectSerials()
        {
            var result = new List<LoanData>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT LOAN_SERIAL,
                                        CLOSE_DATE
                                        FROM OPENQUERY(@linkedserver,'
                                        SELECT
                                        l.Serial AS LOAN_SERIAL,
                                        l.CLOSE_DATE
                                        FROM core.loan l
                                            INNER JOIN core.account la ON la.serial = l.parent_serial
                                            INNER JOIN core.person p ON p.serial = la.primary_person_serial
                                            INNER JOIN core.ln_type lt ON lt.serial = l.type_serial AND lt.CRED_REP_PORTFOLIO_TYPE = ''M''
                                            INNER JOIN core.share s ON s.serial = l.IMPOUND_SHARE_SERIAL AND s.TYPE_SERIAL IN (SELECT serial FROM core.sh_type st WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE ''%Escrow%'')
                                            INNER JOIN core.account sa ON sa.serial = s.PARENT_SERIAL
                                        LIMIT 500
                                        ');".Replace("@linkedserver",LinkedServer);

                connection.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    LoanData tempObj = new LoanData(Convert.ToInt64(reader["LOAN_SERIAL"]), Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CLOSE_DATE"]));

                    result.Add(tempObj);

                }
            }
            return result;
        } 
    }
```

Please help, I'm not sure what else needs to be done to satisfy VS.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your `LoanData` class is internal??

Comment: This looks confusing to me. You have a interface ILoanSelector with the IEnumerable<LoanData> and then combining it with the LoanSelector while having the Public IEnumerable<Loandata> SelectSerial imbedded in the same class. Shouldn't that be in its own class?

Comment: Make sure the `LoanData` class is also declared as `public`.

Answer (score -1):

Going out on a limb here. Not sure what you are trying to do. But I think you want something like this:

```
namespace EscrowAnalysis
{
public class foobar
{
    public IEnumerable<LoanData> SelectSerials()
    {
        var result = new List<LoanData>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT LOAN_SERIAL,
                                    CLOSE_DATE
                                    FROM OPENQUERY(@linkedserver,'
                                    SELECT
                                    l.Serial AS LOAN_SERIAL,
                                    l.CLOSE_DATE
                                    FROM core.loan l
                                        INNER JOIN core.account la ON la.serial = l.parent_serial
                                        INNER JOIN core.person p ON p.serial = la.primary_person_serial
                                        INNER JOIN core.ln_type lt ON lt.serial = l.type_serial AND lt.CRED_REP_PORTFOLIO_TYPE = ''M''
                                        INNER JOIN core.share s ON s.serial = l.IMPOUND_SHARE_SERIAL AND s.TYPE_SERIAL IN (SELECT serial FROM core.sh_type st WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE ''%Escrow%'')
                                        INNER JOIN core.account sa ON sa.serial = s.PARENT_SERIAL
                                    LIMIT 500
                                    ');".Replace("@linkedserver", LinkedServer);

            connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                LoanData tempObj = new LoanData(Convert.ToInt64(reader["LOAN_SERIAL"]), Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CLOSE_DATE"]));

                result.Add(tempObj);

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public interface ILoanSelector
{
    IEnumerable<foobar> GetFoobars;
}

class LoanSelector : ILoanSelector
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; }
    public string LinkedServer { get; private set; }

    public LoanSelector(string connectionString, string linkedServer)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linkedServer)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(linkedServer));

        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        LinkedServer = linkedServer;
    }

}
}
```